# Disabling alphabetic letters and special characters in Visual Basic.NET

Tags: vb.net

Im new to visual basic and im unsure on how to disable alphabetic and special characters.

I Only want the user to be able to input numbers.

Im using this code im know there is an easier way to do it and all help is appreciated

I get the message box when I input alphabetic characters and when I input numbers. i dont want to get the message box when i input numbers.

```
Private Sub txtCustom_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtCustom.KeyDown

    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter) Then

        e.SuppressKeyPress = True

        If (e.KeyCode = Keys.A Or Keys.B Or Keys.C Or Keys.D Or Keys.E Or Keys.F Or Keys.G Or Keys.H Or Keys.I Or Keys.J Or Keys.K Or Keys.L Or Keys.M Or Keys.N Or Keys.O Or Keys.P Or Keys.Q Or Keys.R Or Keys.S Or Keys.T Or Keys.U Or Keys.V Or Keys.W Or Keys.X Or Keys.Y Or Keys.Z) Then

            Beep()
            MsgBox("Please Input A Numerical Value")
            txtCustom.Text = ""

        Else

            RandNumAllow = txtCustom.Text

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This code seems to work only when you type the Enter key and in that case the char could not be a letter. Are you sure to have posted the right code?

Comment: There's nothing more annoying than a program that punishes the user like that.  It's like applying a small electric shock, your user will quickly get fed up with it.  Instead, use the Validating event and, say, Decimal.TryParse() to check the input.  And ErrorProvider to supply a subtle error indication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the KeyPress event instead:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, _
                              e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
  e.Handled = Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)
End Sub
```

But this won't stop someone from using the clipboard.  It's probably better to use the MaskedTextBox control instead.

Comment: I decided to use a masked text box, thanks for the help, its not completely how i wanted it but thanks it was so much faster

Comment: This does not block (Shirt + a number) special characters.

Comment: This will also disable delete and back space how can they be enabled?

Comment: @TheOnlySmartBoy Place a `If Not e.KeyChar.Equals(Convert.ToChar(Keys.Back)) Then` condition.  The delete key works for me, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response this code will solve all the issues, copying from clipboard and shift + number for special characters as it uses the TextChanged event try it out.

```
    Dim charactersAllowed As String = "1234567890"
      Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim theText As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim Letter As String
    Dim SelectionIndex As Integer = TextBox1.SelectionStart
    Dim Change As Integer
    For x As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.Text.Length - 1
        Letter = TextBox1.Text.Substring(x, 1)
        If charactersAllowed.Contains(Letter) = False Then
            SystemSounds.Beep.Play()
            theText = theText.Replace(Letter, String.Empty)
            Change = 1
        End If
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = theText
    TextBox1.Select(SelectionIndex - Change, 0)
End Sub
```

You can replace the value of charractersAllowed with whatever characters you want to allow

Answer (score 0):

The code you were looking for I think looks like this.

For the keypress event on whatever text or input box your trying to control input into

```
If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso 'restricts anything but number keys
    e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then 'allows use of backspace
    e.Handled = True
End If
```